# Double Entry to Run Script

Tags: bash, busybox

I have a bash script running on a BusyBox linux install.

When I run my script, at the prompt I have to enter `yes` and the following is output:

```
    Remove existing upgrades stored on this device?

Please answer yes or no.

    Remove existing upgrades stored on this device? Please answer yes or no.

    Remove existing upgrades stored on this device?
```

On the second entry of `yes` the it mvoes into and runs the commands under yes in the `case` loop.  Any ideas why I have to enter it twice?

Here is an example of the code I am using:

```
while true; do
    read -p "   Remove existing upgrades stored on this device? " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* )
        echo "  Moving into folder."
        echo "  Removing existing upgrade files."
        echo "  Moving back to original folder."
        echo "  Complete.";
    break;;
        [Nn]* )
        echo "  Enough space is available."
        echo "  This script can be run again if required.";
    break;;
        * ) 
        echo "Please answer yes or no."
        echo "";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: If I have to do then i would convert the input in lower case or uppercase then put it into case statement

Comment: «Any ideas why I have to enter it twice?» I tried your script from the prompt of `bash` and it worked fine, no need for entering twice my answer. Next I started a `busybox` session, as in `busybox sh`, and from the new prompt I executed again your script, again no problem.  In both cases I tried every combination of yes, not and maybe that I could think of.  Moral, it seems to me that you have a problem with your specific issue of `busybox` and that you should consider adding more details to your question.

Comment: @gboffi Thanks, I also have a Fedora machine where the script runs as expected, but on my BusyBox machine it asks for the double input.  I have included as much information as I can provide, and was hoping that possibly someone had come across a similar situation and might have been able to help me!

Comment: Did you trying running exactly this script or some other variation (for example instead of echo you do other things that breaks the functionality)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have redeveloped the script, this time using an `IF Statement` with my solution below.

If anyone has a suggestion in how to keep the `while` loop I would still love to hear it.

```
read -p "   Remove existing upgrades stored on this device? (y/n) " RESP
if [ "$RESP" = "y" ]; then
    echo "  Moving into folder."
    echo "  Removing existing upgrade files."
    echo "  Moving back to original folder."
    echo "  Complete.";
else
    echo "  Enough space is available."
    echo "  This script can be run again if required.";
fi
```